# Ajax form set textbox value onsubmit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

after submit the form using ajax i cant set the value on the multiple textbox correctly, here's my form

```
<form id="searchForm" action="process.php" method="post">
<input id="cust_code" name="cust_code" required>
<input id="cust_code1" name="cust_code1" disabled>
<input id="cust_name" name="cust_name" disabled>

<button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

process.php

```
$cust_code = $_POST['cust_code'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT code,cust_name FROM information WHERE code=$cust_code") or die(mysql_error());
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

javascript:

```
var formData = {
            'cust_code': $('#cust_code').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST',
            url         : 'process.php',
            data        : formData,
            dataType    : 'json',
            encode          : true,
            success: function(data)          // recieved data from process.php
            {
                var code = data[0];              
                var cust_name = data[1];           

                // Update id value
                document.getElementById('cust_code').value = code;
                document.getElementById('cust_code1').value = code;
                document.getElementById('cust_name').value = cust_name;


            }
        })
```

the value of cust_code and cust_code1 changed after submit, but not for cust_name

any ideas?

EDIT: the id's has been use on another page(php include) so that make the input wont change, solved!

Comment: Did you check if your variable cust_name is blank ?

Comment: Also, check the value of cust_name in browser console using console.log(cust_name)

Comment: i did check in the console.log(data);  and notice i get the variable i need from the database, its just wont set the value to the textbox

Comment: try deleting the cache and try again!

Comment: please check any where cust_name is not used in this page

Comment: just in case here is my log Object {0: "864895023688086", 1: "ZULFAKAR", code: "864895023688086", cust_name: "ZULFAKAR", success: true, message: "Success!"}

Comment: @Dipesh what do you mean by is not used in the page?

Comment: if in page this id is used then only first id is consider and replace value of that id tag

Comment: but then i also try this one with no luck document.getElementById('cust_name').value = "TESTING";

Comment: make sure there is only 1 cust_name id on the page.

Comment: @atinder, yes i only had 1 cust_name id

Comment: do you see your input when you type `document.getElementById('cust_name')` in console ?

Comment: @atlinder, just because im using php include function i didnt notice that this id's has been use on the another page so that make sense the input was no changes, thank you :)

Comment: @ZulfakarZukri If you solved your problem, post the solution as an answer (yes, even if it's your own question) rather than an edit, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same IDs have been used on another page(php include) so the input value won't change, changing the ID to cust_names seems to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can assign value by this way also in JQuery:

`document.getElementById('cust_code').val(code);`

or

`document.getElementById('cust_code').attr('value',code);`